# Cómo soluciono mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Aquí esta mi código

```
  <section id="mainResultado">
        <?php
             include("conexion.php");
            $db = conectar();

       $cantidad = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagewebsites WHERE titulo LIKE %$BusquedaGet%;");
       $sql = $db->query("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites WHERE titulo LIKE %$BusquedaGet% ORDER BY ID DESC");

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '$row[titulo]';
    }

       mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        ?>
    </section>
```

Quiero que puede hacer un `while`, con un `div` pero no sé como.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [mysqli_query ()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) retornará un conjunto de resultados de una consulta de tipo `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` o `EXPLAIN`.

**Cuando la consulta *(query)* es incorrecta, [mysqli_query ()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) retornará `false`**, es aquí donde se produce el error ya que la función [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) espera como parámetro el resultado de [mysqli_query ()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), pero al producirse el error estaría enviando un valor booleano.

Algunas recomendaciones para evitar este error serían.

- Verificar la consulta a ejecutar, en una herramienta de administración de base de datos, aquí verificamos nombre de tabla, nombre de columnas, valores erróneos *(enviar números en donde se esperaba cadena de caracteres)*  entre otros.
- Asegurarse de no estar mezclando las extensiones `mysqli` y `mysql` y sus funciones. No son lo mismo y no pueden usarse juntos. *(mysql no debería usarse ya !!)*

> Este error no aparece si la consulta no afecta a ninguna fila.
>   **Sólo una consulta con una sintaxis no válida generará este error.**

Para su consulta en particular, debería verificar su consulta ya que tiene un error básico de sintaxis en el `Like`,  recuerde que este debe ir entre comillas.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                     WHERE titulo LIKE '%$BusquedaGet%' ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

Además decida que consulta ejecutará ya  que tiene dos `querys`. Para concluir 2 recomendaciones

- No mezclar los estilos de programación en su código bien lo hace Orientado a Objetos o estilo procedimientos.
- Tener cuidado con [Inyección de Código SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) , su código es muy vulnerable al realizar la concatenación de variables directamente. *(Añadiré un ejemplo empleando PDO)*

  ```
  // Instancia de la conexión con los datos requeridos
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=midatabase', 'user', 'password');
  $BusquedaGet = 'x';//valor para el ejemplo
  $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
  $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                        WHERE titulo LIKE ? ORDER BY ID DESC");
  //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
  //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
  $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
  //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
  foreach($data as $row) {
       echo $row['titulo'];
  }
  ```